# Convert varchar to float on substring with a inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following error when I do an Inner Join.

Message: Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

```
INNER JOIN
Table1
on 
substring(Table2.WLKITA, charindex('-',Table2.WLKITA)+1,5) = Table1.JDDOCO
```

JDDOCO is a float
WLKITA is a nchar

Comment: Why do you store your data in such a strange way?

Comment: You can cast `Table1.JDDOCO` to `nchar`. I agree with jarlh its an odd way to store data, but I've worked with weirder (and I know db design is often out of your hands)

Comment: This may be due to a row with bad data format. You should explore your data. Simplest way is to select in a separate field the result of `SUBSTRING` function and manually explore, or try to select additional help results. Furthermore, this is a bad-practice-join-clause. I would suggest creating a computed persisted column in `Table2` like this (convert to FLOAT could be added also): `ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD FloatValue AS SUBSTRING(WLKITA, CHARINDEX('-', WLKITA)+1, 5)`. Then use this new field in your join: `... ON Table2.FloatValue = Table1.JDDOCO`

Comment: I would suggest that you delete this question.  Then ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Any database support Cast() function to convert data from one type to another. In this case, your substring should be cast to float.

```
INNER JOIN Table1 on  cast(substring(Table2.WLKITA, charindex('-',Table2.WLKITA)+1,5) as float) = Table1.JDDOCO
```

Not all values can be convertible, in that case, you can try use TRY_CONVERT() method.